# Starting coefficient vector for GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I would like to know how R chooses its starting coefficient vector for a GLM when its `start` argument is left blank and defaults to `NULL`. For my personal implementation of a GLM, I have simply initialized $ \boldsymbol \beta_0 $ to be all $1$s. However, while this generally is fine, it can cause the iterative algorithm to diverge.

Basically, I am just looking for a simple algorithm/formula that takes into consideration the data points and family of the GLM to choose the original coefficient vector, $ \boldsymbol \beta_0 $.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why chose $\beta_0 = 1$ and not $\beta_0 = 0$ as your default values?

Answer (score 1):

R's `glm` does not (by default) start with an initial value for $\beta$, it starts with an initial value for $\mu$.  The initial value for $\mu$ depends on the family; it is close to $y$ but chosen to be in the domain of the likely link function.  For example, for binomial, with $y=r/n$,
$$\mu=\frac{r+1/2}{n-r+1/2}$$
and for Poisson, $\mu=y+0.1$, and for Gamma, $\mu=y$.

The initialising value for $\mu$ is used to compute the working response and working weights, and these are used to compute the first value of $\beta$ (after the first iteration)

You *can* specify an initial `beta`, and for some link/variance combinations you have to (eg, `binomial(log)`, where the obvious $\beta=0$ doesn't work but $\beta^T=(-1,0,0,\dots,0)$ does)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much searching and going through papers on the theory behind GLM, I found [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Falg_genlin_gzlm_model.htm) algorithm for the initial values, which numerically agrees with R using `maxit = 1` to force R to output its initial coefficient estimates.

Comment: The link is broken - would you know by any chance a still working link or paper for this, as I was struggling with the same problem?